# Sum of each row is $m$, prove that $m$ divides the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a question from our reviewer for our exam for linear algebra. I just want to have some ideas how to tackle the problem.

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with integer coefficients, such that the sum of each row's elements is equal to $m$, show that $m$ divides the determinant.

Comment: Hint: If one replace the $1^{st}$ column vector by the sum of all column vectors, the determinant remains the same and...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a guide: Why is the "all 1's" vector an eigenvector of $A$? What is its eigenvalue? How does $\det(A)$ relate to the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: A matrix with integer entries can have non-integer eigenvalues. How can you sure the product of the remaining eigenvalues is an integer?

Comment: (Sorry, deleted a dumb reply...here's a better one:) Since $A$ has integer entries, all eigenvalues are algebraic integers and so the product of the remaining eigenvalues is an algebraic integer equal to a rational number, and so is an integer.

Comment: that sounds much better.

Comment: ok thanks... I somehow think I got your point...

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is probably better, but I offer this as an alternative.

Let B be an upper triangular matrix of 1s and 0s.  For example, 4x4:

$B = \begin{array} {c c c c }
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}$

Let $C = A \times B$.  Since $det(B) = 1$ then $det(C) = det(A)$.  By the definition of matrix multiplication, the last column of C is m.  For example:

$C = \begin{array} {c c c c }
... & ... & ... & m\\
... & ... & ... & m\\
... & ... & ... & m\\
... & ... & ... & m\\
\end{array}$

$det(C) = m \cdot det(some sub matrix) - m \cdot det(someothersubmatrix) + \dots$

Since C is an integer matrix, the determinant of each submatrix is an integer, so m divides det(C), so m divides det(A).

Not exactly a very conceptually useful proof, but not a difficult one either.

Comment: thanks for the illustration. this made me visualize the problem clearly

Comment: +1. I like this answer more, but I think it is probably better to set $B$ as $\pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1}$. In other words, we only need to add the first $n-1$ columns of $A$ to the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $n \times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ whose row sums all equal to $m$, i.e.

$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = m, \quad\text{ for } 1 \le i \le n \tag{*1}$$

Let $\text{adj}(A) = (b_{ij})$ be its [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).
We know

$$\text{adj}(A) A = \det(A) I_n
\quad\iff\quad
\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} a_{jk} = \det(A) \delta_{ik}\quad\text{ for } 1 \le i, k \le n
\tag{*2}$$
where $\delta_{ik}$ is the [Kronecker's delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). In RHS of (*2), if we fix $i$ to $1$ and then sum over $k$, $(*1)$ will imply:

$$m \sum_{j=1}^n b_{1j} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n b_{1j} a_{jk} = \det(A) \sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{1k} = \det(A)$$
When $a_{ij}$ are all integers, so do $b_{ij}$. As a result $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n b_{1k}$ is an integer and hence $m$ divides $\det(A)$.